How to catch Django's OperationalError exception thrown in django-main-thread
I use a Postgres 16.2 database in my Django 5.0 project configured like so:
### settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASS',
        'HOST': 'DB_HOST',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

It works well, no issue here.
However, when I simulate a database outage (typically, I'm stopping the database service on my computer), I end up with an exception that I cannot manage to catch:
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 275, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 277, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "api-db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 1073, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 1010, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 136, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 581, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 89, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 63, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 316, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 292, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 274, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 275, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 277, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "api-db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

The exception is thrown in thread django-main-thread before entering the view.
I tried to use a middleware, but it doesn't help:
from django.db.utils import OperationalError
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response


class OperationalErrorMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        super().__init__(get_response)

    def __call__(self, request):
        try:
            return self.get_response(request)
        except OperationalError:
            return Response({'status': "DB_ERROR"}, status=status.HTTP_503_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)

I also tried to use Django's handler500 and DRF (Django REST Framework) EXCEPTION_HANDLER, but these handlers do not catch the exception either.
This exception results in an empty response for the client (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in Chrome) which is bad.
How can I catch this exception in order to show a more "user-friendly" error?

I generally agree with AKX's answer but I am assuming that you're also testing this out by stopping the database mid request, etc. Assuming that handler500 should very much catch the error, it just does not because you're running with DEBUG=True and the custom handlers don't run in debug mode.

There's self.check_migrations() in the traceback - this happens before your server is even running to properly accept connections, when Django is checking whether it should show you a "you have N migrations that haven't been run" message.
This wouldn't happen with a production server such as uwsgi or gunicorn (because only the development runserver runs these checks), and that's why I don't see a great reason for you to try to handle this particular error either.
(That said, if you do really want to capture this error, you'd subclass the runserver Command to catch the exception.)

I was dealing with a similar problem. The error may be occurring elsewhere.
In my case, turns out, if you have a query as such:
def get_important_stuff():
    try:
        return MyModel.objects.filter(is_important=True)
    except OperationalError:
        return []

And then use it in a template:
{% for model in get_important_stuff %}
    <li>{{ model.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}

You will still get an OperationalError. This is because the query isn't actually run (or even connects to the database) until the template engine actually retrieves the values (after it gets the query).
If you force the query set to evaluate (eg. by using list()), then you will get the error within the try/except block:
def get_important_stuff():
    try:
        return list(MyModel.objects.filter(is_important=True))
    except OperationalError:
        return []

